# why is mat-autocomplete not showing my loading spinner?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

i'm trying to utilize angular material in my angular 11 project, one of my pages contain a mat-autocomplete component. i would like this component to show a loading spinner when i request something.
this is my code :

component.ts

```
this.searchServiceProviderCtrl.valueChanges
    .pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        tap(() => {
            this.loading = true;
        }),
        switchMap( (value) => this.serviceProviderAutocompleteService.searchByQuery(value)
        )
    )
    .subscribe( (response) => {
        this.serviceProviders = response;
        if (isNullOrUndefined(this.serviceProviders) || this.serviceProviders.length === 0) {
            this.emptyServiceProviders = true;
            this.loading = false;
        }
    });
```

component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Search" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="searchServiceProviderCtrl">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngIf="loading" class="is-loading">
            <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
          </mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngIf="emptyServiceProviders">Aucun résultat</mat-option>
          <ng-container *ngIf="!loading">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let serviceProvider of serviceProviders" [value]="serviceProvider">
              <span><b>{{serviceProvider.lastName + ' ' + serviceProvider.firstName}}</b></span>
            </mat-option>
          </ng-container>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

first time i wasn't able to see the loader, and i figured out that my service was synchronous, so i added a piece of dead code in it to fake a sleep(5000ms) :

```
    searchByQuery(query: string): Observable<any[]> {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
        currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < 5000);
    return of(this.values.filter((v) => v.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1 || v.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1));
}
```

but even with that workaround, i'm never able to see the loading spinner. i added a {{loading}} in the html to debug, and it never toggles to true, even if i pass in tap() => this.loading = true;
does anyone have a clue on why the loading boolean never updated in the html ?

Comment: Can you post your code (or minimal reproducible code) to Stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Your searchByQuery is still synchronous since you're doing a busy wait. Since Javascript is single threaded, you lock the browser tab for 5 seconds and your spinner doesn't show.

To make searchByQuery async with Rxjs, you can use this:

```js
import { delay} from 'rxjs/operators';

searchByQuery(query: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return of(this.values.filter((v) => v.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1 || v.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1))
        .pipe(delay(5000));
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU very much, it helped a lot.